# In a multi-player game where one player becomes invisible, is the data about the invisible player sent to the enemy game clients?

Tags: networking, multiplayer, anti-cheat

In my 3d FPS game, there is a feature where a player could have it's character become invisible for some time. The character is only invisible, they're still *there* and can move around: the other players can try predict where they are and shoot them, and if they succeed the invisible character becomes visible again.

I'm worried about cheaters using aim bots and I'm wondering how I should handle the invisible characters in this context.

Comment: Why do you ask this? Why is this important to you? (This could influence the answer you get.)

Comment: idk dude i just wanna learn a bit more about how stuff like this work, me and few guys on a dc server were asking this question whether you could create an aimbot that can track invisible(since one guy who has been playing that game for years has pretty much mastered how to track invisible people, he got a fanmail saying he's using hacks) so I just wanted to know if that is even possible, ik it depends on what game I'm playing etc but I just wanted to know generally how it works

Comment: We can't answer "how this works generally" because there is no "one way" of doing things, and companies tend to not reveal how they do things. We can answer questions "in the game I'm developing, how can I achieve X". The answer I posted is geared toward that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As much as you can, you should not send the data that a player does not need to play the game, for two reasons: bandwidth reduction and cheat prevention.

This means that if a character in the game world becomes invisible, the server should send the information to the clients that the character is no longer part of the game world. When the character becomes visible again, the server should send information about what character to create and where to place in the game world.

This *could* be a bit hard to implement depending on the architecture of the game client and the server (e.g. if games are created with all the characters at the start of the game session, and it's difficult for the client to create a new character after the start), then sure, a flag could be sent to the clients telling them that the character is now invisible and should not show it. The server should probably also send "fake" coordinates along this flag to help prevent cheat.

---

Is not sending information about where the invisible characters are enough to completely prevent cheating using aim bots? I don't think it is. Not sending the data could *help* preventing aim bots tracking invisible characters, but if there is enough money to be made, someone could develop a "more advanced" bot that "thinks like a human" and predicts the coordinates of the invisible characters. If you can figure out that Character A is traveling at X m/s in direction Y, and you can figure out that in 3 seconds they'll be at about spot Z in the game world, then one could program their aim bot like this. (To be honest, I'm pretty sure this already exists.)